# Caffe CNN training process falls into a loop

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, hdf5

I have a question regarding caffe, but it may be that it's a more general question about the teaching process of CNNs and deep learning.

Basically, the issue is that I've been testing multiple architectures with the NIH chest X-ray sample dataset which contains 5606 images. I extracted the data into 5 `.h5` files, 1000 images each and resized them to 224x224. I omitted the 3 channels images to be consistent (because most of them are in grayscale). So my input shape is `(batch_size, 1, 224, 224)`. It's just binary classification as I labeled the images with `0 - no finding, 1 - any finding`.

I decided to use the `MobileNet` architecture, just changed the last layers output size to 2.

My issue it that each time I run the training process it seems like the training process falls into a loop. The network just loops around a set of values for loss and accuracy. I tried changing solver parameters, batch sizes, changing the net architecture, but it's always the same - it just differs when it comes to exact values.

Here's a gist with my training log which contains my net architecture, the solver file and the whole output:

https://gist.github.com/ouadakarim/34ac5744fadfd63a25c806b651bba0fb

To better illustrate my problem here's a plot for the above log with the loss and accuracy:
[image: Training learning curve plot]

Another example for a training process (different batch size and solver params):
[image: Another learning curve]

As you can see it always loops around the same values. I'm not sure what may be the issue, but I have a few ideas:

1) My sample set, containing 5000 images, is not enough to teach the net properly.

2) The solver is not properly configured (learning rate).

3) The net architecture is too complicated.

I also tried using simple net architectures at first, but the results were even worse.

I would be very grateful for any suggestion what could be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice a mistake:

you set: 
`use_global_stats: true`
in your batch norm layers

but that's wrong while in training
you should set it `false` 
or simply delete all `use_global_stats: true`

without claiming, caffe will use default value: 
(`use_global_stats: true` in testing 
and 
`use_global_stats: false` in training)

Comment: Many thanks, seems like that's it. I copied the deploy files and probably didn't notice that. I will run a new teaching process and let you know if that solved my issue and of course approve the answer. Thanks!

Comment: in the end it seems like it's learning like before, but it may be because the dataset is to small. Thanks for pointing the issue with `use_global_stats` out. It seems like now the values don't repeat exactly the same.